# Hibernate parse exception

Tags: hibernate

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
>     org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:523)
>     org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
>     org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
>     org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
>     org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

I am using hibernate in my struts application and I am getting this error when I run my code.

What does it mean?

Comment: Your configuration is invalid - `Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml`. Either run it through an XML validator or post it here (removing passwords and sensitive data of course).

Answer (score 0):

It means that your cfg.xml file is not correctly validated, there is an element which was not properly closed(may be mapping or other configuration elements).
If you are using an IDE, you can open the file and right click to let IDE validate XML file, to pin point exact location where the mistake took place.